# Developing GUI for program

Tags: java, flash, user-interface

I have developed a java program as a part of my homework and have to build "really good" GUI for it as is the demand.

I would like to know if I can develop a flash based gui and then run my java code behind it since I have learnt flash before ??

Since I have some time constraint I don't think I would be able to implement full dragabble features using swing and java applets.

Please do suggest the best way I should complete my GUI in period of 2-3 days.

Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "standard" way to do this is to create a Swing GUI which can be very basic or quite complex, and no, don't try to do this with flash as it will be difficult if not impossible to mesh this with your current Java code.  If you already know some Swing coding, this can be do-able within 2-3 days.

You can find the Swing tutorials here: [Swing Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/overview/index.html)

Comment: As an aside changing my java code to work as an applet would be difficult or that depends on the code ???

Comment: It all depends on the code.  If your current program, the one that will act as the "model" for your GUI, is well constructed though, it can be used in either a stand-alone GUI or applet un-modified.  I try to gear my GUI's to create JPanels, and that way I can use them in stand-alone GUI's by inserting the JPanel into the contentPane of a JFrame or an applet by inserting it into the contentPane of a JApplet (or JDialog, JOptionPane, JWindow,... etc).